# How do I add a placeholder for vertical scrollbar with twitter bootstrap 2.0?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In the earlier version of [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) their was a placeholder for the vertical scrollbar so if the content didn't require one the page maintained it's layout.  If the page grew the scrollbar became enabled and didn't cause your pages content to shift to accommodate the scrollbar. Does anyone know how to accomplish this in TBS 2.0 or CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google found this:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 1px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

and I don't see any repercussions so far.  I am using fixed and not fluid.  I would be curious the reasoning behind getting rid of the permanent vertical scrollbar considering I just put it back.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I'm using fixed also. Not sure why they got rid of it...maybe a mistake?

Comment: That did the trick.  I modified it a bit: html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-size: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}